# Redux expecting the reducer to be a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-devtools

Redux is throwing me:

> Error: Expected the reducer to be a function.
>   at lines

*from index:*

```
const { store } = configureStore();
```

*from configureStore:*

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, devToolsEnhancer())
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Root from './Root';
import './index.css';
import App from './whitesheet-components/App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';

const { store } = configureStore();
const MOUNT_NODE = document.getElementById('root');

const load = Component =>
  render(
    <App>
      <Component store={store} />
    </App>,
    MOUNT_NODE,
  );

load(Root);

registerServiceWorker();
```

**configureStore.js**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { devToolsEnhancer } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import rootReducer from './rootReducer';

const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
export default function configureStore(initialState = {}) {
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, devToolsEnhancer());

  if (isDevelopment && module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept('./rootReducer.js', () => {
      const nextReducer = require('./rootReducer').default; // eslint-disable-line global-require
      store.replaceReducer(nextReducer);
    });
  }

  return { store };
}
```

**rootReducer**

```
import mockReducer from './mockReducer';

export default { mockReducer };
```

**mockReducer**

```
export default function reducer(state = { hola: 'as' }, { type }) {
  switch (type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Can't find the bug. First time creating a redux store with devtools plugin support by myself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're exporting an object instead of a function in your root reducer.

rootReducer

```
import mockReducer from './mockReducer';

// export default { mockReducer };
export default mockReducer;
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked. How can I export multiple reducers if I cant wrap them in an object?

Comment: @victor.ja I suggest using a different file per reducer

Comment: well you can `export default { mockReducer, secondReducer }` and when importing do `import { mockReducer, secondReducer } from './mockReducer'`